# SQL Server 2005 select for XML path with union in sub-selection problem

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2005, subquery, for-xml-path

I'm rather experienced with SQL server "select for XML path" queries but now i run into a strange problem.

The following query works fine:

```
select 
(
     select
     'Keyfield1' as "@Name",
    t1.Keyfield1 as "Value"
    from MyTable t1
    where 
    t1.KeyField1= t2.KeyField1 and
    t1.KeyField2= t2.KeyField2
    for xml path('Field'),type, elements 
) as 'Key'
from MyTable t2
for XML path('Path') , elements XSINIL, root('Root')
```

This will result (for a dummy dataset) in this XML:

```
<Root>  
  <Path>
    <Key Name="KeyField1">
      <Value>DummyValue1</Value>
    </Key>
  </Path>
</Root>
```

In my result of this (part of a bigger) statement i need the 2nd keyfield too:

```
<Root>  
  <Path>
    <Key Name="KeyField1">
      <Value>DummyValue1</Value>
    </Key>
    <Key Name="KeyField2">
      <Value>DummyValue2</Value>
    </Key>
  </Path>
</Root>
```

So i changed my (sub)query with a union-select to:

```
select 
(
     select
     'Keyfield1' as "@Name",
    t1.Keyfield1 as "Value"
     union all
     select
     'Keyfield2' as "@Name",
    t1.Keyfield2 as "Value"
    from MyTable t1
    where 
    t1.KeyField1= t2.KeyField1 and
    t1.KeyField2= t2.KeyField2
    for xml path('Field'),type, elements 
) as 'Key'
from MyTable t2
for XML path('Path') , elements XSINIL, root('Root')
```

But now i get the error *"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."*

I know it is possible to have multiple records in a subquery with for XML path witch results in multiple elements. But i don't understand why this can't be done with a union.

Can someone put me in the right direction how to accomplisch the XML with the 2 keyfields in my (sub)query?

Thanx you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your subselect is that the first part isn't referring to any table at all (no `FROM-`clause).

This listing gives me the output you requested:

```
declare @mytable table (
keyfield1 nvarchar(20),
keyfield2 nvarchar(20)
)

insert into @mytable values ('Dummyvalue1', 'Dummyvalue2')
select * from @mytable

select 
(
     select
     'Keyfield1' as "@Name",
    t1.Keyfield1 as "Value"
    from @mytable t1
    where 
    t1.KeyField1= t2.KeyField1 and
    t1.KeyField2= t2.KeyField2
    for xml path('Field'),type, elements 
) as 'Key'
from @mytable t2
for XML path('Path') , elements XSINIL, root('Root')


select 
(
    select * from (
      select
     'Keyfield1' as "@Name",
    t1.Keyfield1 as "Value"
    from @MyTable t1
    where 
    t1.KeyField1= t2.KeyField1
     union all
     select
     'Keyfield2' as "@Name",
    t3.Keyfield2 as "Value"
    from @MyTable t3
    where 
    t3.KeyField2= t2.KeyField2) a
    for xml path('Field'),type, elements 
) as 'Key'
from @MyTable t2
for XML path('Path') , elements XSINIL, root('Root')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example, but does this get you what you need?

```
select 
    (
        select
            'Keyfield1' as "@Name",
            'Blah' as "Value"
        for xml path('Key'),type, elements 
    ),
    (
        select
            'Keyfield2' as "@Name",
            'Blah' as "Value"
        for xml path('Key'),type, elements 
    )
for XML path('Path') , elements XSINIL, root('Root')
```